# Rust Arc/Mutex Try Macro Borrowed Content

Tags: error-handling, rust, mutex, borrow-checker

I'm trying to do several operations with a variable that is shared across threads, encapsulated in an `Arc<Mutex>`. As not all of the operations may be successful, I'm trying to use the `try!` macro, or the `?` operator, to auto-propagate the errors.

Here's a minimum viable example of my code:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref BIG_NUMBER: Arc<Mutex<Option<u32>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(174)));
}

pub fn unpack_big_number() -> Result<u32, Box<Error>> {
    let big_number_arc = Arc::clone(&BIG_NUMBER);
    let mutex_guard_result = big_number_arc.lock();
    let guarded_big_number_option = mutex_guard_result?;
    let dereferenced_big_number_option = *guarded_big_number_option;
    let big_number = dereferenced_big_number_option.unwrap();

    // do some subsequent operations
    let result = big_number + 5;

    // happy path
    Ok(result)
}
```

You will notice that in the line where I declare `guarded_big_number_option`, I have a `?` at the end. This line is throwing the following compiler error (which it does not when I replace the `?` with `.unwrap()`:

```
error[E0597]: `big_number_arc` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:32:30
   |
 7 |     let mutex_guard_result = big_number_arc.lock();
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Now the thing is, it is my understanding that I'm not trying to use `big_number_arc` beyond its lifetime. I'm trying to extract a potential `PoisonError` contained within the result. How can I properly extract that error and make this propagation work?

Additionally, if it's any help, here's a screenshot of the type annotations that my IDE, CLion, automatically adds to each line:

[image: CLion screenshot of code snippet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock()` function returns `LockResult<MutexGuard<T>>`. [Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/type.LockResult.html) says the following:

> Note that the Err variant also carries the associated guard, and it can be acquired through the into_inner method

so you're essentially trying to return a reference to a local variable (wrapped into `PoisonError` struct), which is obviously incorrect.

How to fix it? You can convert this error to something with no such references, for example to `String`:

```
let guarded_big_number_option = mutex_guard_result.map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much! Would there be a way though to get an actual error instance? The clone method does not appear to be supported on `PoisonError`, for example. I'm not saying String is bad, I'm just curious whether there's something more idiomatic,